# How to show text box on mouse move c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to show a inherited text box control on mouse over on the form. But text is not displayed. Below is my code.

```
        private ChartCalloutBox m_calloutbox = null;
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.MouseMove += Form2_MouseMove;

        }

        void Form2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (m_calloutbox == null)
            {
                m_calloutbox = new ChartCalloutBox();
            }
            m_calloutbox.Location = e.Location;
            m_calloutbox.Show();
        }

        internal class ChartCalloutBox : TextBox
        {

            public ChartCalloutBox()
            {               
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void InitializeComponent()
            {
                this.SuspendLayout();
                this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(350, 170);
                this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(130, 40);
                this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(130, 40);
                this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                this.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Brown;
                this.Name = "CalloutBox";
                this.Text = "Callout Rect";
                this.ResumeLayout(false);
                // 
            }
        }
```

Any one help on this how to show the text box on mouse over. and the text box place should be change based on the mouse position.

Thanks,
Bharathi.

Answer (score 2):

Add your control to controls collection.

Code should be like

```
        void Form2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (m_calloutbox == null)
            {
                m_calloutbox = new ChartCalloutBox();
                this.Controls.Add(m_calloutbox);
            }
            m_calloutbox.Location = e.Location;
        }
```